# Passing lambda as a template parameter? ( c++20, lambdas in unevaluated context)

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20

I know this question has been asked before, but none of them addressed the c++20 lambdas.

I've been looking at the new c++20 features, and one of which caught my eye is the possibility of having lambdas in unevaluated contexts.

I've seen that you could write code like the following on Jason Turner's video:

```
std::unique_ptr<int, decltype([] (FILE* f) {fclose(f);})>;
```

which suggests that `std::unique_ptr` can take a lambda parameter.

So I tried implementing a lazy math-like sequence class which looks like the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
template <typename func, typename T> 
struct Sequence
{
    T operator[] (int i) {
        return func(i);
    }
};
int main() {

    auto u = std::vector{1 , 2, 3, 4};
    auto v= Sequence<decltype([u] (int i) {return u[i];}) , int>();
    std::cout << v[1];
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is that the sequence class is defined as a function from N -> T (like in math), and that I pass this function at compile time as a template parameter.
However, I get the error "no matching call for lambda".
How can this be solved?

I could store the function in a std::function at runtime, but I can't afford the overhead it brings.

Comment: Hint: `func` is the type of the lambda, not the lambda itself. To get the lambda itself you need to pass it somewhere

Comment: @user202729 Can't I call the lambda knowing only the type if each lambda has a different type? Also, if I can't, how does Jason Turner's example with std::unique_ptr work? Surely it calls the lambda?

Comment: Lambdas are allowed to be default-constructed from it's type in `c++20`. But you can't default construct a capturing lambda.

Comment: @super I still get the same error if I pass in a non-capturing lambda, ie [] (int i) {return i;}

Comment: That's cause your're trying to call the type, instead of creating an instance of the lambda and calling it. Have a look [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6GG3Tr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is that your lambda captures `u`. Therefore, you the lambda cannot be instantiated from just its type in C++20. However, if you pass the lambda directly as a parameter, not its type, and you use an array instead of a vector (`vector's` constructor and `operator[]` are not `constexpr`), you can get it to work:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
template <auto func> 
struct Sequence
{
    consteval auto operator[] (int i) const {
        return func(i);
    }
};
int main() {
    constexpr auto u = std::array<int, 4>({1, 2, 3, 4});
    constexpr auto l = [=](int i) { return u[i]; };
    constexpr auto v = Sequence<l>{};
    static_assert(v[1] == 2);
    std::cout << v[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Even without optimizations enabled, [`operator[]`](https://godbolt.org/z/jE8EPr) is never called at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. This answers my question. What I really wanted though was Sequence not to be evaluated at compile time, ie that it could depend on runtime types such as std::vector. But I guess that's not possible...

Comment: Actually on C++20, `vector` was changed and can be used at [compile time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at), but it doesn't seem to be yet accepted by gcc (`constexpr auto u = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4};` fails). You can get a sequence created at compile time that has `operator[]` evaluated at runtime, but then its state must be constructible at compile time as well. To use it against a vector, you'd need to pass the vector as extra method parameter instead, for instance.